# Selecting a column from an intermediate table in a Peewee Join

Tags: python, mysql, peewee

I am creating an application using Peewee. I have a query that returns User objects which are linked to the current User by a many-to-many relation on the table Relationship. In the contacts queries I would like to select the 'confirmed' column from Relationship somehow alongside each User object, so that I can return that information in the list.

```python
class Entity(BaseModel):
    image = CharField(null=True)
    isgroup = IntegerField(db_column='isGroup')
    name = CharField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Entities'

class Relationship(BaseModel):
    confirmed = IntegerField()
    entitya = ForeignKeyField(db_column='entityA', rel_model=Entity, to_field='id')
    entityb = ForeignKeyField(db_column='entityB', rel_model=Entity, related_name='Entities_entityb_set', to_field='id')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Relationships'

class User(BaseModel):
    activated = IntegerField()
    attributes = TextField()
    email = CharField()
    entity = ForeignKeyField(db_column='entityID', primary_key=True, rel_model=Entity, to_field='id')
    lastaccess = DateTimeField(db_column='lastAccess')
    password = CharField()
    signupdate = DateTimeField(db_column='signupDate')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Users'

    def contacts(self):
        contacts = []
        requested = User.select(User, Entity).join(Relationship, on=(User.entity == Relationship.entitya)).join(Entity, on=Relationship.entitya).where(Relationship.entityb == self.entity, Entity.isgroup == False)
        requests = User.select(User, Entity).join(Relationship, on=(User.entity == Relationship.entityb)).join(Entity, on=Relationship.entityb).where(Relationship.entitya == self.entity, Entity.isgroup == False)
        for u in requested:
            contacts += [u]
        for u in requests:
            contacts += [u]
        return contacts
```